# Не получается глубокая копия JS

Tags: javascript

```js
const incoming0bj = {
    formatted_address : "Washington Square, New York, NY 10012, Сполучені Штати Америки",
    geometry: {
        location: {
            lat: 40.7308838,
            lng: -73.997332
         },
         viewport: {
            northeast: {
               lat: 40.7333674,
               lng: -73.99379435000002
            },
            southwest: {
               lat: 40.72847220000001,
               lng: -74.00132615
            }
         }
      },
      name: "Washington Square Park"
};

let outgoing0bj = {};

for (let key in incoming0bj) {
  outgoing0bj[key] = incoming0bj[key]
  if (typeof incoming0bj[key] === 'object') {

    for (keys in incoming0bj[key]) {
      outgoing0bj[key][keys] = incoming0bj[key][keys]
    }
  }

}
console.log(outgoing0bj)
```

[image]

Comment: Можете просто `const newObj = {...oldObj};`

Comment: @entithat, нужна глубокая и иммутабельная копия циклом for in

Comment: Ну так у вас рабочий код. Правда только на один уровень вложенности.

Comment: @entithat, так тоже не работает,не могу понять в чём соль

https://prnt.sc/1130cox

Comment: Настоящую глубокую копию делают рекурсией, а что должны были пояснить красные стрелочки вообще непонятно

Comment: да я в курсе,что глубокую копию делают рекурсией,просто для личного опыта было интересно попробовать циклом.
Вдруг,кому интересно,вот так это выглядит))
https://prnt.sc/1137qjq

Comment: @VladyslavHerasymenko, нет, так оно не должно выглядеть. А что если у вас будет сотки вложеных объектов?

Comment: @entithat, если были бы сотки,я б не пытался сделать это циклом. Сделал бы сразу рекурсией(внизу прикрепил ответ с рекурсией),но поскольку объект не большой,стало интересно поиграться с циклом,но сразу не получилось реализовать, поэтому здесь и спросил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const incomingObj = {
    formatted_address : "Washington Square, New York, NY 10012, Сполучені Штати Америки",
    geometry: {
        location: {
            lat: 40.7308838,
            lng: -73.997332
         },
         viewport: {
            northeast: {
               lat: 40.7333674,
               lng: -73.99379435000002
            },
            southwest: {
               lat: 40.72847220000001,
               lng: -74.00132615
            }
         }
      },
      name: "Washington Square Park"
};

function getCopyObj(source) {
  let result = {};

  for (let key in source) {
    result[key] = {};
    if (typeof source[key] !== 'object') {
      result[key] = source[key]
      continue;
    }
    result[key] = getCopyObj(source[key]);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(getCopyObj(incomingObj));
```

У меня более компактно получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Глубокую копию делают через рекурсию

```js
const incoming0bj = {
  formatted_address: "Washington Square, New York, NY 10012, Сполучені Штати Америки",
  geometry: {
    location: { lat: 40.7308838, lng: -73.997332 },
    viewport: {
      northeast: { lat: 40.7333674, lng: -73.99379435000002 },
      southwest: [1, 2, 3, { a: 456 }]
    }
  },
  name: "Washington Square Park"
}
// Для примера делаем ссылку на самого себя
incoming0bj.foo = incoming0bj

const isObject = (v) => typeof v === 'object' && v !== null
const isArray = Array.isArray

function copy(o, parent = [/* избегаем бесконечного копирования */]) {
  if (parent.includes(o)) {
    return null // !!! любое значение
  }
  if (isArray(o)) {
    parent.push(o)
    let a = []
    for (let i of o) {
      a.push(copy(i, parent))
    }
    parent.pop()
    return a
  }
  if (isObject(o)) {
    parent.push(o)
    let a = {}
    for (let [p, v] of Object.entries(o)) {
      a[p] = copy(v, parent)
    }
    parent.pop()
    return a
  }
  return o
}

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(copy(incoming0bj), null, 2)
)
```

UPD: Изменил что'б небыло бесконечного копирования

Answer (score 0):

```js
const incoming0bj = {
  formatted_address: "Washington Square, New York, NY 10012, Сполучені Штати Америки",
  geometry: {
    location: {
      lat: 40.7308838,
      lng: -73.997332
    },
    viewport: {
      northeast: {
        lat: 40.7333674,
        lng: -73.99379435000002
      },
      southwest: {
        lat: 40.72847220000001,
        lng: -74.00132615
      }
    }
  },
  name: "Washington Square Park"
};

const newObj = {...incoming0bj};

incoming0bj.name = '';

console.log(incoming0bj);
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: Результат будет такой же, нужна глубокая и иммутабельная копия циклом for in